# ICU4J LocaleData.MeasurementSystem

Tags: java, internationalization

I wish to use ICU4J library for i18n. 
Can any one suggest how to use **LocaleData.MeasurementSystem** for measurement i18n.
Some sample codes will be appreciative.

Thanks for reading.
Jerry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ICU is a good choice, but its API is horrible. It basically forces you to use wrappers.
The LocaleData class is not that useful, but you can learn few things.

#### Quotation and locale patterns

If you want to know how to quote a word, LocaleData can give you this information:

```
ULocale germanLocale = ULocale.forLanguageTag("de-DE");
LocaleData localeData = LocaleData.getInstance(germanLocale);
String openningQuotation = localeData
        .getDelimiter(LocaleData.QUOTATION_START);
String closingQuotation = localeData
        .getDelimiter(LocaleData.QUOTATION_END);
String quoted = MessageFormat.format("{0}{2}{1}", openningQuotation,
        closingQuotation, "Das buch");
System.out.println(quoted);
```

The output:

> „Das buch“

It uses locale-specific punctuation, as you can see. I don't quite get where it could be useful, for quotes should be extracted as part of the text and it is translator's job to get them right, but...

There are other things directly in this class, like `getLocalePattern()` or `getLocaleSeparator()`, but these are used by ICU to display the list of Locales, i.e.:

> Deutsch (Deutschland),Polnisch (Polen)

I don't really see how you can use them in your application.

#### Measurements

You might want to know what measurement system to use for given country. This is where `LocaleData.MeasurementSystem` comes in. Again, the class doesn't reveal too many information, but at least you can tell apart countries that uses SI system from countries that still uses things like miles:

```
private void showDistance(ULocale locale) {
    int distance = 160;
    MeasurementSystem system = LocaleData.getMeasurementSystem(locale);
    String unit;
    if (system.equals(LocaleData.MeasurementSystem.SI)) {
        unit = "km";
    } else if (system.equals(LocaleData.MeasurementSystem.US)) {
        unit = "mi";
        distance = (int) (distance / 1.6);
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException("Unknown measurement system.");
    }
    String distanceMessage = MessageFormat.format(
            "The distance between cities is {0} {1}.", distance, unit);
    System.out.println(distanceMessage);
}
```

Calling it for different locales (German and US) produces:

> The distance between cities is 160 km.
>   The distance between cities is 100 mi.

The only problem is, I believe they still use miles in UK, while using seconds, kilograms and other staff. Tough luck. Or maybe I am wrong.

#### Paper size

If you know the paper size in millimeters (ha, ha), you may use `LocaleData.PaperSize`:

```
private void showPaperSize(ULocale locale) {
    PaperSize paperSize = LocaleData.getPaperSize(locale);
    String msg = MessageFormat.format("The paper size is: {0}x{1} mm",
            paperSize.getWidth(), paperSize.getHeight());
    System.out.println(msg);
}
```

For German and US the result is:

> The paper size is: 210x297 mm
>   The paper size is: 216x279 mm

Perhaps you ca use the `MeasurementSystem` to know if you can show the size in inches (1 inch = 25.4 millimeters) and re-calculate the size if needed.
The only way to know is paper size is A4 or Letter, is to simply compare its width and height against predefined enum class for example. Great.

#### Exemplar sets

The last thing that `LocaleData` could give you is the list of exemplar characters. I am not sure how it would be that useful, but here it is:

```
private void showExemplarCharacterSets(ULocale locale) {
    printSet("Standard:",
            LocaleData.getExemplarSet(locale, LocaleData.ES_STANDARD));
    printSet("Index chars:",
            LocaleData.getExemplarSet(locale, LocaleData.ES_INDEX));
    printSet("Auxiliary:",
            LocaleData.getExemplarSet(locale, LocaleData.ES_AUXILIARY));
    printSet("Punctuation:",
            LocaleData.getExemplarSet(locale, LocaleData.ES_PUNCTUATION));
}

private void printSet(String name, UnicodeSet set) {
    System.out.print(name);
    for (String s : set) {
        System.out.print(" ");
        System.out.print(s);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

The result of calling `showExemplarCharacterSets(germanLocale)` is:

> Standard: a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z ß ä ö ü
>   Index chars: A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z Ä Ö Ü ß ä ö ü ſ ẞ K ss
>   Auxiliary: a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z ß ä ö ü
>   Punctuation: a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z ß ä ö ü

The standard set is the thing used to create words in this language. It doesn't necessary hold true for ideographic languages, but in this case you can see standard German alphabet.
Index set is suppose to display characters to use in indices - for alphabetic languages it would be the first letter in a word.
Auxiliary should give you the letters that are external to given alphabet, and punctuation should probably show some punctuation... At least that's how I understand it. I am not sure how [CLDR](http://cldr.unicode.org/) localizers see it, for I am unable to check this in the survey tool (which is horrible, by the way).
Anyway, I doubt that you can use these sets.

Comment: Pawel can you suggest the best java API to do the i18n and l10n. Also is it possible to automatically identify the units for a measurement based on Locale?. ex: i just pass the locale and distance, if the locale is "US", it should display distance in "Miles" otherwise in "Kilometer".